# Convert a JSON object to nested form fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Anyone know of a good way to convert a JSON object to nested form fields.

For example: consider a JSON object:

```
{'a':{'b':{'c':'1200'}}}, 'z':'foo', 'bar':{'baz':'1', 'id':2}}
```

I should get:

```
{'a[b][c]':'1200', 'z':'foo', 'bar[baz]':'1', 'bar[id]':2};
```

Any ideas?

I am currently using jquery and it feels like something like this already exists, if not I can simply roll my own with a crazy algorithm, but I'd rather use something with a proven track record.

Comment: What's a nested form field? Are these fieldset elements? I don't quite understand what algorithm you're even implying to get from the first object to the second.

Comment: Um, what, exactly, is this mess? You may need to provide some clarification because this doesn't make a whole lot of sense without more context...

Comment: Would the fact that you already can refer to elements as obj['a']['b'['c'] change your form-field traversing algorithm to a little better?

Comment: I have the same problem, I am using FormData to pass some file attachment but using the form.append method is very tedious if I have a big nested form.

Answer (score 3):

So, I have no clue why you want to do what you say you want to do, and I hope you will fill us all in, but this code should be close enough for you to be able to tweak it (this is based on [**some code of mine that I use to find differences in JavaScript object graphs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264430/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-differences-between-two-javascript-object-graphs)):

```
function doStrangeThing(obj) {
   var propertyChanges = [];
    var objectGraphPath = [];
    (function(obj, refObj) {
        if ( obj.constructor == Object || (obj.constructor != Number &&
             obj.constructor != String && obj.constructor != Date && obj.constructor != Boolean &&
             obj.constructor != RegExp && obj.constructor != Function)) {
            for (var property in obj) {
                objectGraphPath.push((objectGraphPath.length > 0) ? "[" + property + "]" : property);
                if (obj[property].constructor != Function) {
                    if (!refObj[property]) refObj[property] = {};
                    arguments.callee(obj[property], refObj[property]);
                }
                objectGraphPath.pop();
            }
        } else if (obj.constructor != Function) {
            if (obj != refObj) {
                propertyChanges.push("\"" + objectGraphPath.join("") + "\":\"" + obj.toString() + "\"");
            }
        }
    })(obj, {});
    return "{" + propertyChanges.join(",") + "}";
}
```

Here is what I did to test it:

```
doStrangeThing({'a':{'b':{'c':'1200'}}, 'z':'foo', 'bar':{'baz':'1', 'id':2}});
```

Which results in this value:

```
{"a[b][c]":"1200","z":"foo","bar[baz]":"1","bar[id]":"2"}
```

Hope that is useful to you in some way...

Comment: once this reaches the serverside, in php it becomes a nested hash map.

Comment: Well, if it works for you, please mark it as the answer - I don't know anything about PHP or the need for this, but obviously you have your reasons. :) Again, it could probably use a little tweaking to make it do things EXACTLY as you would like it to, but this was relatively quick for me to test and play with, since I had written this code quite a while ago...

Comment: When I say "tweak," by the way, I mean to get the value types working correctly - I see that you wanted the value of "bar[id]" to be the literal number 2, not a string ("2") - you could tweak the code to test to see if something is a number and if so, not use quotations; etc.

Comment: Jason Bunting: +1 for doing it for free. I know how that's ironic. :)

Comment: @unknown (yahoo): Since you seem to have jQuery at you disposal, I feel obliged to tell you that you may be better off sending JSON to the server (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) and have PHP evaluate the JSON (http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). I would say that this has the type of track record you were looking for.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, I have to assume the OP knows what he/she is doing, because the results he requested look like useless @*&#$!! to me. I feel an inkling that there is a better way to do what he is intended on doing with this than to do it this way, but I thought it would be "fun" to see if I could get it to work, as nightmarish as it looks. :)

Comment: @JasonBunting this is very relevant if you re stuck using FormData like me :).

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = {'a':{'b':{'c':'1200'}}}, 'z':'foo', 'bar':{'baz':'1', 'id':2}}
```

is internally equivalent to

```
{['a']['b']['c']:'1200', ['z']:'foo', ['bar']['baz']:'1', ['bar']['id']:2}
```

Please note that this is not JSON object anymore.

You already can refer first object properties in this way:

```
var z = obj['a']['b']['c']   // 1200
```

Is it enough for your needs? Do you really want to convert property names to variables?

Comment: I had to laugh when I read this answer because I think I sense the same feeling I had when I read the question - i.e. WTF is this guy going to do with this mess?! It was an interesting exercise nonetheless, but I don't know what "unknown" is doing with this stuff in PHP. Weird stuff.

Comment: Actually, I got what he wanted. Quite weird, but it have some sence. However, there are plenty of simpler algorithmic ways to achieve the same goal... And there would be a big mess with variable names and namespaces, if it should have been implemented for common usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend a function that takes a nested JSON object and turns it into a HTTP POST string. jQuery will accept that for all of its arguments that require HTTP parameters.

I have written and used the function below in several production apps (use at your own risk):

```
$.httpSerialize = function(items, parentName) {
    var serializedItems = [], serialize = arguments.callee, encodeItem =     function(key, value) {
        if (value === null || typeof value == 'undefined') return value;
        if (value.constructor == Array) {return serialize(value, key);}
        return (value.constructor == Object)
            ? serialize(value, key)
            : (value === true || value === false)
                ? key+"="+new Number(value)
                : key+"="+encodeURIComponent(value);
    };

    if (items.constructor == Array) {
        parentName = parentName || 'item';
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var key = parentName+'['+i+']', value = items[i];
            serializedItems.push(encodeItem(key, value));
        }
    } else {
        parentName = parentName || '';
        for (var key in items) {
            var value = items[key];
            if (parentName) {
                serializedItems.push(encodeItem(parentName+'['+encodeURIComponent(key)+']', value));
            } else {
                serializedItems.push(encodeItem(encodeURIComponent(key), value));
            }
        }
    }
    return serializedItems.join("&");
};
```