# Find difference between 2 documents on mongoDB from the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb 2.4.4 and I want to compare 2 documents, then print their differences only using the mongo shell. Is there a way to compare them? Something like:

```
db.collection.compare({first_doc: objectID("blablalba"), sec_doc: objectID("blalba2")})
```

and the output would be something like

```
{diff1:{latitude:{first_doc:10.000, sec_doc:20.000}},diff2:{}}
```

where latitude is the name of the field that had a difference.

The output doesn't need to be exactly like that, but give the same functionality.
Thanks

Comment: You'd write the JS to do the comparisons you need and execute it. What have you tried so far? If you're wanting to repeat it frequently, you could follow: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Comment: actually I only need this for debugging purposes. I thought it was possible directly from the mongo shell. But thanks for the link anyway, it's cool.

Comment: You thought what was directly possible from the mongo shell? You can write scripts there too. It can become difficult to manage/edit if the code is more than a few lines long. You can also pass a JS file to execute to the shell: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#evaluate-a-javascript-file `mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js`

Answer (score 7):

Just declare native javascript function that can compare two objects in a way you need, then write a code like this:

```
obj1 = db.test.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5176f80981f1e2878e840888")})
obj2 = db.test.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5176f82081f1e2878e840889")})
difference(obj1, obj2)
```

Some native javascript difference functions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264430/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-differences-between-two-javascript-object-graphs) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects)

P.S. You can also load some third party js libs from shell like this:

```
load("D:\difference.js")
```

Hope this help.