# How can I check for duplicate documents in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is an example of a nested document that I have in my collection:

```
"person" : [
  {
    "title" : "front-end developer",
    "skills" : [
      {
        "name" : "js",
        "project" : "1",
      },
      {
        "name" : "CSS",
        "project" : "5",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title" : "software engineer",
    "skills" : [
      {
        "name" : "Java",
        "project" : "1",
      },
      {
        "name" : "c++",
        "project" : "5",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a simple way of determining whether other documents are identical to this object e.g. has the same keys, value and array indexes? Currently my method of checking for duplicates is very long and requires multiple nested loops. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there is not, you have to compare it yourself. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276065/find-difference-between-2-documents-on-mongodb-from-the-mongo-shell)

Comment: What exactly do you want to find out? Do you want to know if you have duplicate documents in your database already? Or do you want to check if there is a document in your database that matches the one you are trying to insert? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks @GrégoryNEUT I'll check out think link. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @dnickless, I'm trying to find out the latter. I have a document in my collection already and I need to query all the other documents to find an identical match in terms of keys, values and index ordering. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a list of identical (except for the `_id` field, obviously) documents in your collection, here is how you can do that:

```
collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "_id": 1, // keep the _id field where it is anyway
        "doc": "$$ROOT" // store the entire document in the "doc" field
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "doc._id": 0 // remove the _id from the stored document because we do not want to compare it
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$doc", // group by the entire document's contents as in "compare the whole document"
        "ids": { $push: "$_id" }, // create an array of all IDs that form this group
        "count": { $sum: 1 } // count the number of documents in this group
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "count": { $gt: 1 } // only show what's duplicated
    }
})
```

As always with the aggregation framework, you can try to make sense of what exactly is going on in each step by commenting out all steps and then activating everything again stage by stage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @dnickless! I'll have to look into the aggregation framework as it is something that is new to me. May I kindly ask, how would I modify the aggregate function if the objects within the skills array contained a nested array of objects? Thanks!

Comment: I think you would not need to change anything. My solution is entirely generic. It does not make any assumptions about your document structure.

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate your help, thanks again!

Comment: Hey @dnickless! I've been playing around with your answer and came across another issue which I've posted a question about here: stackoverflow.com/questions/46412412/…. Do you mind taking a look at it please? It's similar to this question and I'm stumped!