# How can I check for duplicate nested arrays inside of documents in Mongoose?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

Here is an example of a nested document that I have in my collection:

```
{
  "title" : "front-end developer",
  "age" : 25,
  "name" : "John",
  "city" : "London",
  "skills" : [
    {
      "name" : "js",
      "project" : "1",
      "scores" : [
        {
          max: 76,
          date: date
        },
        {
          max: 56,
          date: date
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "CSS",
      "project" : "5",
      "scores" : [
        {
          max: 86,
          date: date
        },
        {
          max: 36,
          date: date
        },
        {
          max: 56,
          date: date
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a simple way of determining whether other documents have an  identical/duplicate structure to the `skills` array only? e.g. has the same keys, value and array indexes? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just `$group` on `skills` array to get all documents with same `skills` array. Something like `db.collection_name.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":"$skills", "_ids":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}})`

Comment: Hey @Veeram thanks for your answer, I'll give it a go and will let you know :)

Comment: Hi again, I answered your question the other day and you asked me to check out this question, too. I would think, the "comment" you got from @Veeram is the correct answer. No idea, why he didn't post it as such.

Comment: Hey @dnickless, thanks for responding. I did try Verram's answer but it returns all of my documents and not the documents which have the same contents in the skills array. Would you happen to know why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you get that:

```
collection.aggregate({
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$skills",
        "docs": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
        },
        "count": {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "count": {
            $gt: 1
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for developers with the same skillset, you can use the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator:

```
var john = db.developers.findOne(...);
var devs = db.developers.find({ 'skills.name': { $all: john.skills.map(x => x.name) } });
```

Comment: Hey @Xiaoy312 thanks for your answer! I was wondering if it would be possible as well as more efficient to use the aggregate function?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the matched documents. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364709

Comment: I wrote a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396614/how-can-i-check-for-duplicate-documents-in-mongoose?noredirect=1&lq=1. Essentially I was to query documents that contain duplicate data. In this case it's the skills array. So I want to find other users who have an identical skills array structure only e.g. same number of items, same keys e.g. name and same values e.g. js. You can think of it as a snapshot. Let me know if that makes sense!