# Find difference of the two objects

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

Is there any way in underscore.js to get the difference between two objects,
tried with _.difference dosen't work.
My object is like:

```
$scope.ABC = {};
$scope.ABC.fruits = {};
$scope.ABC.vegetables = {};
$scope.ABC.fruits.places = [];
$scope.ABC.fruits.type = [];
$scope.ABC.vegetables.places = [];
$scope.ABC.vegetables.type = [];
```

The id is common for ABC object.
now I have another object XYZ same as ABC, but which can have places or types value different from ABC.

Any way I can find the difference between the two.

_.difference(ABC,XYZ) dosen't work.

Comment: `_.difference` works on arrays, not on objects.

Comment: Please add `XYZ` object and the desired outcome of `difference`.

Comment: maybe you could have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264430/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-differences-between-two-javascript-object-graphs

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for: [_.contains(list, value, [fromIndex])](http://underscorejs.org/#contains)

> Returns true if the value is present in the list. Uses indexOf internally, if list is an Array. Use fromIndex to start your search at a given index.

Now loop `_.contains()` for every *attribute* of `$scope.ABC` and check if it is present in `$scope.XYZ`. If not, push it e.g. into another *array*.

*Offtopic: I suggest using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for various reasons*

Comment: this returns boolean, whereas my I need to return the difference.

Comment: I was misunderstanding your question, see updated answer.